# Upload a video in my web site using ASP.NET MVC 5 when I have two projects in my solution

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I solve my problem? When I use this code in one project in a solution, it runs fine, but when I put it in a solution, it throws an error.

This is my error:

[image]

This is my code:

[image]